# Notation - stacked vectors

Tags: machine-learning, notation

I am trying to self-study Kevin Murphy's book on machine learning. i am trying to be 100% sure that i understand the notation in the book. . I am however struggling to understand what is meant with the line following "similarly, if we...".

I read this as a column vector, running verticallly with index j from 1:D (dimensions) and each entry itself being a vector (as the x's are bolded) running with index i from 1:N. However - i am confused - as would this not be a matrix? i am surely not understanding something here - it would be great if someone could be so kind to give an example / visual on this would look in practice.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that he means the following. The column vector $\mathbf{x_{1}} = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
2\\
3
\end{array}
\right]$ would be written $\mathbf{x_{1}} = \left[ 1, 2, 3
\right]$ and the column vector $\mathbf{x_{2}} = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
4\\
5\\
6
\end{array}
\right]$ would be written as $\mathbf{x_{2}} = \left[ 4, 5, 6
\right]$ then

$\mathbf{a} = [\mathbf{x_{1}}, \mathbf{x_{2}}] = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
2\\
3\\
4\\
5\\
6
\end{array}
\right]$ and

$\mathbf{A} = [\mathbf{x_{1}}, \mathbf{x_{2}}] = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
1 & 4\\
2 & 5\\
3 & 6\\
\end{array}
\right]$